# Use Applescript to launch multiple instances of an application

Tags: applescript

This is my code. I wanted to run an app (Game Capture HD.app) twice at the same time. But I get this Syntax Error: Expected “"” but found unknown token.

```
on run
    do shell script "open -n /Applications/Game\ Capture\ HD.app"
    tell application "Game\ Capture\ HD" to activate
end run

on open theFiles
    repeat with theFile in theFiles
        do shell script "open -na /Applications/Game\ Capture\ HD.app " & quote & (POSIX path of theFile) & quote
    end repeat
    tell application "Game\ Capture\ HD" to activate
end open
```

Comment: `tell application … to activate` doesn't take an escaped string, just the application name - `"Game Capture HD"` but I've no idea about the rest, whether it will work or not.

Comment: I tried the name but it says name not found :/

Comment: As soon I change this line: /Applications/Game\ Capture\ HD.app to anything it says Expected “"” but found unknown token

Comment: shell script would usually take `"/Applications/appName.app/Contents/MacOS/appName"`

Comment: I have the same script for VLC and it works perfectly here with
do shell script "open -n /Applications/VLC.app"

Comment: Then I've no idea, sorry. Have to wait for someone better than me at Applecsript.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I really hope someone can help me out. I don't understand what's the issue. Are there any other apps which can run multiple applications on Mac?

Comment: "Simplest" way to run an app twice is duplicate it in the Apps folder - but no matter how you do it, the OS will consider them the same app & won't necessarily do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: what you mean by won't achieve what I'm trying to do? 
I just need to run this app twice so I can in one app have different settings than the other. I tried to duplicate your way but it won't work since it does not open the app twice

Comment: That all depends on what you are actually trying to do… there is not enough detail to know. I don't know your app or how it functions either. After your edit - very likely you will have to set the different settings every time you launch both. The last one you quit will set the prefs for both at next launch.

Comment: what I want to achieve is to have the app run same time twice. that's all lol.
the settings within the app takes me 1 sec for each. so Its ok if they reset.

Comment: The usual macOS response to clicking on an app icon once the app is running, or executing the Terminal command `open` on an app already running, is to ignore it. Have you tried actually making a duplicate of Game Capture HD app? The other problem you'll see if you actually get the app running in two instances is that the settings you want to compare will most likely be a single set of preference files which are usually not designed to be accessed by two apps simultaneously, _and_ you may not have any control of the location and naming of these preference files.

Comment: duplicating the app does not work.
why shouldn't it work to open the app twice and use it same time with different settings? 
I can do this with VLC. Should work with other apps too?

Comment: Anyone here who can help me by fixing my AppleScript?

Comment: It's not the applescript that's at fault, it's that the app cannot differentiate between the prefs for both instances. That would need the app's developer to enable the functionality.

Comment: are you sure? since I can open any apps twice with the same script. since I do not get that kind of error above.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why running the app twice?

Comment: because I like to use two different settings same time.

Answer (score 1):

The spaces mess things up. Try:

```
do shell script "open -n " & quoted form of "/Applications/Game Capture HD.app"
```

Essentially, 'quoted form' is for passing text to 'do shell script'. Both the Script Editor and the shell will be interpreting the text and 'quoted form' helps manage that.

Save the following as an application and then if you drop some text files on it, a separate instance of TextEdit will open each. The app and each of the dropped files get wrapped in single quotes for the shell.

```
on open theFiles
    set tApp to "/Applications/TextEdit.app"
    set qApp to quoted form of tApp
    
    repeat with ef in theFiles
        set ppf to quoted form of POSIX path of ef
        
        do shell script "open -n " & qApp & space & ppf
        
    end repeat
end open
```

To see how it breaks down, here it is as a regular script that works with selected files. The `set shCmd…` line returns the command sent to the shell.

```
tell application "Finder" to set theFiles to selection as alias list

set tApp to "/Applications/TextEdit.app"
set qApp to quoted form of tApp
repeat with ef in theFiles
    set ppf to quoted form of POSIX path of ef
    
    do shell script "open -n " & qApp & space & ppf
    
    set shCmd to "open -n " & qApp & space & ppf
    --> "open -n '/Applications/TextEdit.app' '/Users/username/Desktop/style attributes of.rtf'"
    
end repeat
```

To use with a different app, change the value of 'tApp'.

Comment: hey the script runs but I can't open the app twice it.


my code:

on run
 do shell script "open -n " & quoted form of "/Applications/Game Capture HD.app"
 tell application "Game Capture HD" to activate
end run

on open theFiles
 repeat with theFile in theFiles
  do shell script "open -n " & quoted form of "/Applications/Game Capture HD.app" & quote & (POSIX path of theFile) & quote
 end repeat
 tell application "Game Capture HD" to activate
end open

Comment: That's a separate issue. I'm not sure really what you're trying to do (I'm unfamiliar with this app) but it looks like you're trying to open two items with one command (the app and a doc) but you don't have any space between the two. And why do it this way at all? Just 'open' the files (with -n switch) and the app will open automatically. BTW, the 'activate' lines may be redundant.

Comment: If you are trying to open multiple files that aren't associated with the game capture app, (and you need multiple instances of the app for whatever reason) then try this: do shell script "open -n -a " & quoted form of "/Applications/Game Capture HD.app" & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path of theFile)

Answer (score 0):

The escaped space `\`  is the problem. If you simply remove the backslash `\` and leave the space unescaped, you'll get a *different* error, but the script will still fail.  Use the `[[:space:]]` special character instead.

For example,

```
do shell script "open -n /Applications/Game\ Capture\ HD.app"
```

becomes:

```
do shell script "open -n /Applications/Game[[:space:]]Capture[[:space:]]HD.app"
```

It's less readable, but it should work as expected. I can't test it on your specific app and precise use case, but doing the above allowed me to create an AppleScript to successfully open multiple instances of another program with no errors.

From reading your comments, I see that you might want the multiple instances of the program to reference different settings. Depending on your setup, you may still encounter problems with one instance over-writing changes to the settings made by the other instance. See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390324/1043704) for a possible work-around.

You got lucky in your previous experience duplicating VLC.app and didn't run into this issue before, since its path and name didn't have any spaces.

Comment: While `[[:space:]]` works it's just much easier to use a _double backslash_ instead, or use _single-quotes_ around the _application pathname_. Just keep in mind that in **Terminal** a _single backslash_ escapes the _space_ but when using the `do shell script` _command_ the _single backslash_ itself must be escaped, thus use a _double backslash_ and no need to use `[[:space:]]`. It's senseless to type 11 characters when 2 will suffice!